# When I select a DropdownButton value, the entire Accordion section collapses (react-bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been creating a table with an accordion component (react-bootstrap) and the behavior of this table is expand and collapse some subtables per row parent table. In the rows of table parent I put a dropdown (react-bootstrap) that I use it to set others dropdown's inside, but my issue is that I've tried to set the stopPropagation method when I select a Dropdown value, to entire Accordion section not collapse, but still collapse. I've tried create a customToggle method to expand/collapse accordion section but there isn't changes.

My code it's some like this:

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <table className="table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <td className="">HEAD1</td>
          <td className="w-25">HEAD2</td>
          <td className="w-25">HEAD3</td>
          <td className="">HEAD4</td>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     array.map((m, index)=>{               
         return (
             <tbody key={m.id}>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><b>{m.qty}</b> {m.name}</p></td>
                    <td>
                      <DropdownMultiselectParent /> //When select a value of this dropdown collapse the entire section of accordion
                    </td>
                    <td className="w-25"></td>
                    <td>
                       <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={m.id}>
                             Group details <span className="material-icons">expand_more</span>
                       </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="4">
                       <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={m.id}>
                          <SubTableResults  /> // inside of this component I set others child's dropdown's 
                       </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>)
     </table>
</Accordion>
```

Is it something I'm not setting correctly? Thanks.